# Bound class method with with generic type

Tags: flowtype

Here is a demo  of the problem on [tryflow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKATnDgM4A8AkhngLYAqueAfGALxgDeqYYASzr1yALjC0GzfAG0AugBo+YOADsAynhh4AxhnEAKIQ3GSmLAJSd2ANzgCAJqgC+6HTACG5cmAAyA8gwaYWk2HmUcUgpxEjIqM1DWZQ89ARs8alUHPAAPcVUAV3oAIzxiZR01QOICvThiA0i4mKj4kJZWK15+fgwACwCAOiaKTjAR8gBuZV6B8kGUjDSMrNyxgAZp-ld+ZQBzPAwAQVT0swMrcQB+BJZwnrBiQ4LiVTB+oYnB4xEZD-nFstMtkcnItmBXMpyAVivQhGYxkZhNdbvgrNZ7j0BFAkQwujMev9hq1BmpNNo9Lj6BYCTsIeh+GoAMIwAQ6ADWF0xsyG0Nh8OEBiJB2OpwygosNO2LnQqG0GDAhRKZTEiqKpWI8jGMgAjAoAEwKADMYLlhxUGi0ugVXAMNg8MAKeHy6rKVg47G4zmmZoVSo1-kC4kDQX9ZXYXFUeCQIYM3EEwlVYeI5AUFvJ1vEZKtemcFiAA)

Essentially I have a class that operates on an array of gerically typed items.

```
type Props<ItemType> = {
  items: ItemType[],
  onSelect: (item: ItemType) => void
}

class List<ItemType> {
  props: Props<ItemType>
  activeIndex: number
  constructor(props: Props<ItemType>) {
    this.props = props;
    this.activeIndex = 0;
  }

  getActiveItem() : ?ItemType {
    return this.props.items[this.activeIndex];
  }

  submitItem(item: ?ItemType){
    if(item) {
      this.props.onSelect(item)
    }
  }

  onClick() {
    this.submitItem(this.getActiveItem())
  }
}


let numbers: number[] = [1,2,3];
let onSelect = (value: number) => {};

let numberList: List<number> = new List({ items: numbers, onSelect: onSelect})
```

This example comes from a react component that I stripped down to more clearly demonstrate the problem.

It mostly  works but ran into problems when I converted `submitItem()` to a bound method:

```
  submitItem = (item: ?ItemType)  => {
    if(item) {
      this.props.onSelect(item)
    }
  }
```

This causes the following error:

```
27:     this.submitItem(this.getActiveItem())
                        ^ Cannot call `this.submitItem` with `this.getActiveItem()` bound to `item` because `ItemType` [1] is incompatible with `ItemType` [2].
References:
8: class List<ItemType> {
              ^ [1]
20:   submitItem = (item: ?ItemType)  => {
                           ^ [2]
```

The method needs to be bound to the class because it will be triggered as a callback from a DOM event.

How do I get the bound method to understand the generic type.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to a problem there with [property initialiser syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) (the [recommended method](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/events/) of ensuring the method is bound to `this`) not creating the same type signature as when a regular class property is used.  I've [raised an issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6070) with a simplified example.

However, in your example you don't seem to need to do this, as your `onClick` method is the one that needs to be bound and passed as the event handler

```
// ...
submitItem(item: ?ItemType): void {
  if(item) {
    this.props.onSelect(item)
  }
}
onClick = () => {
  this.submitItem(this.getActiveItem())
}
// ...
```